# How do I parse a JSON string and print a particular element?

Tags: ruby, json, api, parsing, twitter

I tried get the value from some JSON using Ruby but got:

```
[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
    from jsonpars.rb:61:in `<main>'
```

This is the code I am using for parsing and printing a particular element.
Can you tell me how can I print specific values like `screen_name` or `url` or `text`?

```
json = JSON.parse(response.body)

#json['user'].each do |alerts|
  # do whatever you want with these...
print json.first['user']['screen_name'];
#end
```

This is the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "metadata"=>{
      "iso_language_code"=>"en",
      "result_type"=>"recent"
    },
    "created_at"=>"Wed Apr 15 19:02:27 +0000 2015",
    "id"=>588417116358848512,
    "id_str"=>"588417116358848512",
    "text"=>"@BTS_twt i love India.arie too. My favourite is 'This Too Shall Pass' ",
    "source"=>"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>",
    "truncated"=>false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id"=>588412513093431296,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>"588412513093431296",
    "in_reply_to_user_id"=>335141638,
   }
```

}

Comment: Code looks fine. Could you tell that what's on line number 61?

Comment: hello @Surya ,below is code to print json                                                                                               json['statuses']['user'].each do |alerts|
  # do whatever you want with these...
line 61 >>print json.first['statuses']['user']['screen_name'];
end

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of giving us the entire JSON string, reduce it to the *bare* minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem you're seeing. Anything more and you're wasting space and time as we wade through a lot of unnecessary information.

Comment: @theTinMan sorry, i editied my code and i am able to get correct solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `.first` as you are already getting the hash you need. Using `.first` in this case is getting you the first key-value pair from that hash in the form of an array.

The reason that TypeError is happening is because it thinks you are trying to call an index of that array using the string `'user'` instead of an integer.

Just use:

```
print json['user']['screen_name'];
```

on line 61 instead of

```
print json.first['user']['screen_name'];
```